How do you write functional code that is not point-free (tacit)?
Edit
Based on comments and close-vote flags, I'm seeing that I didn't clearly articulate what I'm trying to ask. So let me state it as succinctly and as straight-forwards as possible.
What does it mean to write non-tacit functional code?
Any answer that answers that question is valid. Everything below is just additional context explaining why I'm asking the question and trying to show my knowledge gap, but if it's just confusing, ignore it.
Original question
Some background
If I were to define functional programming, I would describe it as the art of decomposing problems into small re-usable functions, and then composing those functions together (with pipelines, a compose operator, partial application, etc) to build your program. If you can compose pieces of your program as a series of pure steps in a pipeline, you're doing functional programming. Things like function purity and first-class functions are related to the paradigm and have become very popular concepts, but I don't see them as the core of the paradigm.
I like this definition because it actually feels like I'm describing a paradigm - a way to approach solving a problem, as opposed to, say, defining functional programming simply as "writing pure functions" - function purity is just a technique, not a whole paradigm. Resources like Wikipedia seem to agree with my general conclusion here, where it describes functional programs as "programs [that] are constructed by applying and composing functions".
If I were to define point-free programming (tacit programming), I would define it in a similar fashion - it's the technique of building functions through partial application or function composition, as opposed to explicitly defining the function by hand, by explicitly naming all of the parameters it takes, etc.
The problem
I'm realizing that my definition for point-free programming largely overlaps with my definition for functional programming - sort of like two sides of the same coin. With functional programming, we're breaking up a problem into pieces and composing those pieces together through the use of point-free programming. However, I know that these two terms aren't meant to be interchangable, and I see plenty of places online that say it's possible to do functional programming without following the point-free style.
Which leads me to my question: How do you write functional code that is not point-free? What would be an example of this (written in whatever multi-paradigm language you'd like - I'm specifically asking for a multi-paradigm language so I can picture what a similar example would look like if it's not written in a functional style at all)? I'm assuming my definitions are off - how are they wrong? What would be a better definition(s)?

This sounds more like a question for a different stackexchange community.  StackOverflow is not really designed for opinion-based questions / answers

Do you know what point-free means? The answer to your question is "you use points", i.e. variables and λ-abstractions.

@craig - the question is fundamentally about the definition of functional programming, and ideally definitions shouldn't primarily be a matter of opinion.

@NaïmFavier - right, but if I use variables, then I'm not composing functions anymore nor am I doing partial application, and then it sort of feels like I'm just doing regular old programming, not functional programming.

Well, you're wrong. λ x. f (g x) is a perfectly cromulent way to express the composition of f and g, and most functional languages define f ∘ g that way.

@ScottyJamison, maybe "theoretical" questions / answers would be a better way to say it

@NaïmFavier - if you want to expound more and turn that into an answer, that would be great. If you say that's an acceptable way to represent function composition, then does that mean programming in a non-tacit functional style just means you're writing functions that try to mimic the behavior of function composition without actually using a dedicated compose function? I guess the advantage would be that if you decide that composition isn't the right approach for a particular function, it takes much less refactoring to change it?

@ScottyJamison "ideally definitions shouldn't primarily be a matter of opinion" – ideally, yes. But there are lots of concepts that have no precise or universally agreed-upon definition. Functional programming is one of those: my take on an explanation, inspired by https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/key-concepts/

"Mimic the behavior"? No, they have the exact same behavior by definition. This is just a matter of syntax.

@NaïmFavier - I agree, the two are interchangeable. What I intended to convey is that, in your example, you confined yourself to a subset of the syntax available in order to get function composition behavior. If, instead, you had written λ x. f x (g x) I don't believe you would call that function composition anymore.

So function composition is a core aspect of functional programming (at least, that's what I'm probably incorrectly assuming), and non-tacit programmers achieve function composition by using a subset of function-definition syntax in places where it's appropriate. I assume this programmer would be intentionally trying to structure some of their functions to behave like the composition of other functions as opposed to writing code as normal, some functions happen to behave like the composition of others, and then calling your program functional.

I looked over @mb21's links - perhaps functional programming is, among other things, more about thinking of programs as expression trees as opposed to lists of instructions. So, in a language like JavaScript, that would mean preferring ternary over if/else, preferring arrow functions with an implicit return over functions with blocks, etc.

On a tangent, it's interesting to consider paradigms as constraints.

@jaco0646 I find Uncle Bob (and his Clean Code book) to be severly outdated and something flat out wrong (like from your link: "don’t use assignment, and therefore don’t have side effects" – that's just wrong, you can still have side-effect without any assignments). But I can highly recommend https://grokkingsimplicity.com as a intro to functional programming.

Functional programming is programming with functions, while point-free programming is programming with combinators. All combinators are functions, but not all functions are combinators.
In order to effectively program with combinators, one needs a fairly rich repertoire of predefined (primitive) combinators to start with. If you go with a minimal set instead... Well, try to program something non-trivial in SKI and see how it goes.
So while an important tool in computation theory and other wonderful branches of mathematics I have no clue about, point-free (a k.a. combinatorial) programming is rarely used in practice in its pure form. If you need a combinator that is not in the predefined set or cannot be easily expressed with previously defined combinators, you just define one as a plain old function and move on.

Note, to the extent permitted by applicable laws, this answer is provided as-is, with no express or implied warranty of any kind. (IOW I don't necessarily know what I'm talking about).
